# Getting java.util.InputMismatchException

Tags: java

The program I'm trying to do:
"Use the file ("Eleven.txt") and delete the records with the marks in English and Science below 80 and marks under 90 in Computer Science"

I have tried adding 'sc.next()' and 'sc.nextLine()' between eng, sci, comp... But still no success.

The value in the "Eleven.txt" file is

```
a
A
10
20
30
b
B
20
30
40
c
C
40
50
60
d
D
60
70
80
e
E
70
8
90
```

"Science.txt" file is a blank file

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class filePg501Ex21{
    public static void main() throws IOException{
        String name1;
        String name2;
        int eng;
        int sci;
        int comp;
        int ch;
        int p = 0;
        
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("Eleven.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("Science.txt");
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(bw);
        
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("Eleven.txt"));
        
        while(sc.hasNext()){
            name1 = sc.nextLine();
            name2 = sc.nextLine();
            eng = sc.nextInt();
            sci = sc.nextInt();
            comp = sc.nextInt();
            
            if((eng >= 80) && (sci >= 80) && (comp >= 90)){
                pw.println(name1);
                pw.println(name2);
                pw.println(eng);
                pw.println(sci);
                pw.println(comp);
            }
        }
        fr.close();
        br.close();
        
        fw.close();
        bw.close();
        pw.close();
        
        sc.close();
        
        File f1 = new File("Eleven.txt");
        f1.delete();
        
        File f2 = new File("Science.txt");
        
        boolean Rename = f2.renameTo(f1);
        if(!Rename){
            System.out.println("Renaming of the file not done");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Renaming done sucesfully");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if they are separated by space, instead of `sc.nextLine();` use `sc.next();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like the error occurs in the second data set. The `sc.nextInt()` is not reading the carriage return after the final grade. So when the loop comes back for the second iteration, the first `name1` field is blank, and the `name2` field is `b`. That means when you read the `eng` value as an int, you get a value of `B`. That is the mismatch.

You should consider adding debug code to show you what the loop is doing to help you find this sort of problem.

There are almost certainly many ways to solve this.

- Read another line after the last grade for instance.
- Read the scores as lines and parse them to ints.